# grep show all lines, not just matches, set exit status

Tags: grep

I'm piping some output of a command to egrep, which I'm using to make sure a particular failure string doesn't appear in.

The command itself, unfortunately, won't return a proper non-zero exit status on failure, that's why I'm doing this.

```
command | egrep -i -v "badpattern"
```

This works as far as giving me the exit code I want (1 if badpattern appears in the output, 0 otherwise), BUT, it'll only output lines that don't match the pattern (as the -v switch was designed to do). For my needs, those lines are the most interesting lines.

Is there a way to have grep just blindly pass through *all* lines it gets as input, and just give me the exit code as appropriate?

If not, I was thinking I could just use perl -ne "print; exit 1 if /badpattern/". I use -n rather than -p because -p won't print the offending line (since it prints *after* running the one-liner). So, I use -n and call `print` myself, which at least gives me the first offending line, but then output (and execution) stops there, so I'd have to do something like

`perl -e '$code = 0; while (<>) { print; $code = 1 if /badpattern/; } exit $code'`

which does the whole deal, but is a bit much, is there a simple command line switch for grep that will just do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your perl idea is not bad.  Try:

```
perl -pe 'END { exit $status } $status=1 if /badpattern/;'
```

I bet this is at least as fast as the other options being suggested.

Comment: Cool, shorter than my perl one liner, too, at least.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ tee /dev/tty < ~/.bashrc | grep -q spam && echo spam || echo no spam
```

Comment: So, the last part is unnecessary, but the first part works... sometimes. I don't understand this, but if I do a echo badpattern | tee /dev/tty | grep -q -v badpattern, it works. BUT, if I put "badpattern" in a file with some other stuff and do cat bpfile | tee /dev/tty | grep -q -v badpattern, it stops working, exit status always comes back 0. So, tough for me to know if it'll work for what I get back from curl (the first command I'm using) or not.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a redirect to /dev/null, hence removing all lines, but you still get the exit code?

```
$ grep spam .bashrc > /dev/null

$ echo $?
1

$ grep alias .bashrc > /dev/null

$ echo $?
0
```

Or you can simply use the `-q` switch

```
   -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet;   do   not  write  anything  to  standard  output.   Exit
          immediately with zero status if any match is found, even  if  an
          error  was  detected.   Also see the -s or --no-messages option.
          (-q is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: But I _do_ want to see all lines. I don't want to filter the lines, I just want to scan them and if there's a match, set the exit code to nonzero. But all lines should be output regardless.

Comment: Missunderstood your Q completely, if you know the length of the output you can do something like this `grep alias -A1000 -B1000` i.e. display 1k lines above and below match i.e all output